# Voix active ou voix passive

Tags: usage, passif, académique, université

A/

> Dans cette étude la question de l'identification des propriétés constitutives effectives d'un objet binaire est abordée.
>
> Cette étude aborde la question de l'identification des propriétés constitutives effectives d'un objet binaire.

B/

> Cette étude aborde la résolution de problèmes inverses de l’estimation de paramètres poroélastiques.
>
> Dans cette étude la résolution de problèmes inverses de l’estimation de paramètres poroélastiques est abordée.

Dans un contexte scientifique/académique (universitaire), pourrait-on employer la forme passive ou serait-ce mieux d'utiliser toujours la forme active ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La voix passive fait très traduction de l'anglais.

Comment: Il me semblait pourtant que l’anglais privilégiait la forme active.

Answer (score 2):

La forme active permet au lecteur de savoir immédiatement ce que nous souhaitons faire : « aborder » le sujet dans ce cas. 
Elle ne l’oblige pas à attendre la fin de la phrase pour connaître l’action en jeu dans la phrase.