# Question à propos de l'usage des reflexives dans la voix passive

Tags: grammaire, voix-passive

Bonjour

Dans la langue française, il existe plusieurs façons de parler à la voix passive, y compris l'utilisation de "on," des participes, ou bien, des réflexifs. Dans certains cas, il n'existe qu'une façon de parler. Par exemple, on entend souvent, "on m'a dit," mais personne ne dit, "j'étais dit." Il en va un peu de même pour l'usage des réflexifs. Par exemple, on dit souvent, "cette phrase ne se dit pas en français," mais on entend aussi, "on ne dit pas cette phrase." Dans la langue français, est-ce qu'on n'utilise jamais les participes pour parler à la voix passive ? Il me semble que la plupart du temps, on n'utilise que "on" ou des reflexives.

Je vous en remercie d'avance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? Je me demande si cette question a déjà été posée ou bien si les exemples dans les réponses peuvent t'aider. [Quelles sont les utilités respectives de la voix active et la voix passive ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18283/quelles-sont-les-utilit%c3%a9s-respectives-de-la-voix-active-et-la-voix-passive)

Comment: L'utilisation de "on" n'est pas associé de façon caractéristique au passif ; « on » peut être remplacé par un autre pronom indéfini, comme par exemple « quelqu'un », ou même un nom comme « les gens » (rien à voir avec le passif). Donc cette notion est fausse. // Vous affirmez que des participes sont utilisés pour exprimer le passif, mais ensuite vous posez une question demandant si les participes sont utilisés pour le passif. Il est évident qu'il y a une erreur dans votre texte. Est-ce bien de participes que traite votre question ? Revoyez votre question de façon à la rendre cohérente.

Comment: "on m'a dit" vs "j'étais dit.", il y a effectivement un problème. "Je" n'étant pas le COD de dire, on ne peut faire comme ça. Le COD est la chose dite, du coup on peut écrire : "la chose m'a été dite". Ou alors utiliser un verber où la personne est COD : "on m'a informé que" / "j'ai été informé que"

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Non, on dit bien les deux : https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-99741.php

Comment: Il se peut que la personne ait voulu évoquer un verbe pronominal à sens passif ou l'emploi d'un pronom réfléchi. On ne sait pas vraiment. Je vais faire un _rollback_. À l'auteur de préciser.

Comment: @Caroline "Les réflexives" n'existe pas comme terme spécifique de grammaire en français, c'est uniquement un adjectif. Est-ce que tu peux clarifier ce que tu entends par là? Il existe bien *la réflexivité* mais ce mot englobe un peu tout ce que tu décris.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30147/la-voix-passive ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34386/voix-active-ou-voix-passive ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/emploi-de-voix-passive-comme-dans-un-carr%c3%a9-est-translat%c3%a9-pour-a-square-is-tra ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43244/passive-or-active-voice-for-technical-documentation

Answer (score 2):

En français, le sujet d’une construction passive est le complément d’objet direct de la construction active correspondante. Ce n’est pas forcément le cas en anglais où un objet indirect peut devenir le sujet d’une phrase passive ; dans ce cas, traduire directement en français une phrase anglaise passive peut présenter des difficultés.

Ainsi, l’anglais *I have been told* a le sens *(Someone) told (something) **to me*** où *me* est un objet indirect. Je suppose qu’on pourrait l’interpréter comme objet direct par *(Someone) told **me** (to someone else)* mais c’est excessivement rare (il faudrait que le locuteur soit un poème ou autre texte susceptible d’être lu à haute voix) et sans doute peu idiomatique. Le français *<s>J’étais dit</s>* (ou <s>*je suis dit*</s>) est grammaticalement correct, mais correspond forcément à ce deuxième sens.

En français, on peut utiliser *dire* dans un sens de jugement ou d’évaluation (en anglais: *X is said to be...*), auquel cas l’objet de l’évaluation peut être une personne. On peut trouver cette construction au passif à la troisième personne :

> Il est dit colérique

> On le dit colérique [plus fréquent]

Je trouve (français métropolitain) que la première formulation est plus recherchée / soutenue et un peu moins idiomatique que la deuxième, mais tout à fait acceptable.

En revanche, à la première personne, la construction passive me semble incorrecte, sans qu’il s’agisse d’une incorrection grammaticale :

> <s>Je suis dit colérique</s> [jamais entendu]

> On me dit colérique

Dans les deux cas, la tournure indéterminée ou passive est employée pour occulter qui porte le jugement, généralement pour sous-entendre que c’est un avis universel. Si les évaluateurs sont connus, il faudra généralement préférer une tournure active :

> Il est dit colérique par (son employé / sa famille) [correct mais peu idiomatique]

> (Son employé / sa famille / etc.) le dit colérique

> (Son employé / sa famille / etc.) dit qu’il est colérique

Enfin, dans tous les cas, l’usage de "dire" comme jugement appartient à un registre de langue relativement soutenu, on ne peut donc pas le combiner avec un adjectif familier :

> *<s>Il est dit rigolo</s>*

> *<s>On le dit rigolo</s>*

> *On dit qu’il est rigolo*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec le discours, mais pour l'exemple  : *someone told me* se dit très bien en anglais, même si l'on n'*est* pas un poème !